# How to do a find for two different names

Tags: bash, find, ls

We have code that generates a large number of files with names like stdout, stdout.qsub, stderr, stderr.foo, etc.

I would like to do

```
find <dir> -name (stdout|stderr) -exec ...
```

and only find stdout and stderr files, no stdout.qsub, etc.

So I can't do '-name "std*"'.
In this case, I can do '-name "std[eo][ru][rt]"', and it works because there won't be any stdeut files to be found by that search.

Is there a cleaner way to do this than '-name "std[eo][ru][rt]"'?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
find "$dir" \( -name stdout -o -name stderr \) -exec ...
```

Or, with GNU `find`:

```
find "$dir" -regextype posix-extended -regex ".*/(stdout|stderr)"
```

Just note that `-regex` matches against the whole path, more like `-path` than `-name` and the regexp is anchored as if there was an implicit `^` at the start and `$` at the end. Also beware that since `.*` matches any sequence of *characters*, it won't find `stdout` / `stderr` files in directories whose path cannot be decoded as characters in the locale.

Also beware it will fail if `$dir` starts with `-` or happens to match the name of a `find` predicate.

With BSD `find`, you can do:

```
find -E -f "$dir" -- -regex '.*/std(out|err)'
```

Above, the `"$dir"` is passed as an argument to the `-f` option, so there's no ambiguity and no problem with values of `$dir` starting with `-`. `-E` enables extended regexps like for `grep` or `sed`.